# What does “杀牛” mean in this context?

Tags: idioms, slang

In the story I'm reading for class, a man meets a woman online and she asks him what sign he's born under (属什么). He says 牛, and she says "我是杀牛的." He recounts, "就这么两句话一下子就把我打动了." So they arrange to meet in the park and it turns out she's old and gray instead of young and pretty like he expected, and he thinks "直到这个时候我才什么都明白，眼前的这个女人为什么是“杀牛的”了."

What on earth is going on? “杀牛” has to have some idiomatic or slang meaning, right?

Comment: Do you maybe have more context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(From the view of the man), the 1st `杀牛的` means `men born under the Ox sign killer`, the 2nd one means `(real) Ox killer`.

Comment: Thank you! So he thought it meant something like "man-eater," i.e. sexy banter, and it turned out she's a butcher?

Comment: @MissMonicaE Yes, I think so. You might read the story more to confirm whether it conform to the relevant context.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched this paragraph online, and read it's context.
I think the firs "杀牛的" is just a joke to answer the man's animal zodiac, the second one means the man is really really disappointed at the woman, like she killed him...

Comment: This should be the right answer.

Comment: I am not sure...